# Python webscraping page which requires login

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to automate a web data gathering process using Python. In my case, I need to pull the information from https://app.ixml.com.br/documentos/nfe page. However, before you go to this page, you need to log in at https://app.ixml.com/login. The code below should theoretically log into the site:

```
import re 
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser


username = 'email'
password = 'password'

br = RoboBrowser()

br.open('https://app.ixml.com.br/login')

form = br.get_form()

form['email'] = username
form['senha'] = password

br.submit_form(form)

src = str(br.parsed())
```

However, by printing the src variable, I get the source code from the https://app.ixml.com.br/login page, ie before logging in. If I add the following lines at the end of the previous code

```
br.open('https://app.ixml.com.br/documentos/nfe')
src2 = str(br.parsed())
```

The src2 variable contains the source code of the page https://app.ixml.com.br/. I tried some variations, such as creating a new br object, but got the same result. How can I access the information at https://app.ixml.com.br/documentos/nfe?

Comment: Perhaps you could use `follow_link` after logging in?  htttps://robobrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#robobrowser.browser.RoboBrowser.follow_link

Comment: The login form you are trying to submit uses JavaScript and not traditional HTML `action` method. [Robobrowser can't evaluate JavaScript](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser/issues/26). You should look at this API URL which is the URL called by JS when the form is submitted: https://app.ixml.com.br/ajax/validar-form

Comment: There's JS validator on the page. It can be, that form can't be submitted without some validator cookie or smth. Try to login through Chrome and check all POSTed data through the "Network" tab.

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok to have a webpage opening you can try to solve this using [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html). This package makes it possible to create a program that reacts just like a user would.

The following code would have you login:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://app.ixml.com.br/login")
browser.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("abc@mail")
browser.find_element_by_id("senha").send_keys("abc")
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button").click()
```